# Trouble with writing files inside loop (Python)

Tags: python

I've been having trouble with the following piece of Python code. It's running without errors, but it isn't exactly giving me the expected output; no files at all are being written.

```
for l in h:                                                   
    r=l.rfind(",")+1
    s=l[r:-2]
    j=0
    while j<18:
        if s[j]==1:
            f=codecs.open("genre_"+str(j)+".csv","w","utf-8")
            f.write(l)
            f.close()
        j=j+1
```

- `h` is a list of strings, typically something like `1,32,3.5,1112484819,000000000000101100\r\n`
- `s` is the end of a string in `h` , specifically the last number string
- For each 1 in string `s`, the while loop writes the current string of `h` on a correspondingly indexed `genre_[num].csv` file

So, for instance, `h[2]` is the example string above, and the files `genre_12.csv`, `genre_14.csv` and `genre_15.csv` should be written with it. The thing is, after running the code, these genre files aren't even being created.

I've tried other variations of the code ('with codecs.open as f:') but fared no better. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set s to a string with `s=l[r:-2]` and then later check for an int with `if s[j]==1:`

Since the condition is never met there won't be any files written. Check for the string "1" instead and it will work:

```
for l in h:                                                  
    r=l.rfind(",")+1
    s=l[r:-2]
    j=0
    while j<18:
        if s[j]=="1":
            f=codecs.open("genre_"+str(j)+".csv","w","utf-8")
            f.write(l)
            f.close()
        j=j+1
```

`

Comment: Knew it had to be something basic. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the code that is in our for-loop. Indentation is very important in python since there isn't the use of curly brackets or semi-colons. Hopefully this will solve the problem you are having!

:) Derek

```
for l in h:                                                  
    r=l.rfind(",")+1
    s=l[r:-2]
    j=0
while j<18:
    if s[j]==1:
        f=codecs.open("genre_"+str(j)+".csv","w","utf-8")
        f.write(l)
        f.close()
    j=j+1
```

Comment: Also, where you wrote j = j+ 1, you can instead write j += 1. This will save you save typing. :D

Comment: Sorry about the identation; I mistyped. I corrected indentation in the question. Also; thanks for the increment tip